# Responsive Design With Tables In Divs

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is probably quite amateur but I'm stuck nonetheless.
My goal is to have a series of tables in a row, and when the screen shrinks in size, tables fall down a row as necessary to make room. I've somewhat managed to achieve this, but the container for the tables isn't acting as desired.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PncDk.jpg

Image 1: In the first image, both tables can fit on the page in the same row and the container fits properly to the contents (the tables).

Image 2: Once a table drops down (because there is no room for it), the container doesn't react properly and shrink in size to fit the now smaller column.

My current setup is basically

```
<div class="green">
   <div class="red"><table></table></div>
   <div class="red"><table></table></div>
</div>
```

The divs are inline-blocks with auto right & left margins.
The tables are also set to inline-blocks.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Are you open to using front end frameworks like Flexbox?

Comment: No, I'm just using normal CSS. I've never experimented with any CSS frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for, try the following css:

```
.green{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.red{
  display: inline-block;
}
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

You can interchange the width of the green class with whatever width you want for your parent container. Your parent container and your table have width's or else the browser wont know when to display the table on a new line.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/PNzrVR?editors=0100)

Just in case you wanted to see a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) version, here is the css:

```
.green{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
table{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. I want it so that the container (.green) constrains its width to the tables. If you change the background colors you can see how .green takes up space not occupied by the tables.
I guess the problem stems from the fact that I want everything to be dynamic. I want the tables to only be as big as necessary to fit their contents, then the container for the tables to only be as big as necessary to fit the tables.

Comment: I understand now. I dont know if that is possible without giving a width to the parent container. If you dont set a width on the green div then the width is automatically set to auto and it's up to the browser to choose a width. But if you do set a width then you are stuck with the green overflow you see in your second image. Not sure if this makes sense but I am no expert either, just a google search pro.

Comment: I just gave the outer container a max width % so that at least it doesn't look too ugly by hugging the entire width of the page. It's not a huge issue, just something I was trying to figure out to make my page look a little more professional. Thanks for your time and help dude!

Comment: No problem! Wish I could help more, I am curious as to whether what you are asking for is possible. Hopefully someone answers.